# JQuery UI accordion height issue using ajax (MVC)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

When using ajax to fill a panel of a JQuery UI accordion everything works fine but the height of the panel is not content dependent. Actually the panel is one line having a scrollbar.
The script used to fill the panel:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
        header: '> div > h3',
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            var id = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
            id = id.replace("QID_", "");

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAnswers")',
                data: { QuestionId: id },
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#QID_" + id).html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

The parameter autoHeight is set to false to make the panels sortable. Setting it to true doesn't make it better. A workaround is initially filling the panel with blanks:

```
<div id='QID_@item.QuestionId'>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Not the best solution, hopefully. How to get a content dependable the panel height? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to refresh its contents?

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    header: '> div > h3',
    autoHeight: false,
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        var id = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
        id = id.replace("QID_", "");

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAnswers")',
            data: { QuestionId: id },
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#QID_" + id).html(result);
                // Refresh
                $(".accordion").accordion().refresh();
            }
        });
    }
})
```

And I can't find the option `autoHeight` on the documentation. Don't you mean `heightStyle: "content"` instead?

Comment: Thanks, heightStyle will do. Refresh is recursion.

Comment: I've mentioned both just in case.